# In my custom directive decimal to input type="text" decimal places are not shown for whole numbers

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In my current project, we have a requirement where we have an input type="text" instead of input type="number" and we know that this text box will always input decimals. We also wanted to restrict the user to use only numeric keys and decimal point. We have implemented that successfully using a custom directive. But now there is another concern. The input box value has 2-way `ngModel` binding, and we manipulate the values from component. For example, on component load this textbox has a fixed value = 1. In textbox the value is displayed as 1 but we want to display it as 1.0000 in textbox.

We have tried to implement `OnChanges` interface to detect change of `ngModel` and then render the whole number with decimal places but it does not seem to work. Is there anything that we could do about it?

```
Directive Class:
export class AllowDecimalDirective implements OnChanges
{

@Input() decimalPrecision: number = 0;
@Input() inputValue: number = 0;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const element = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.setProperty(element, 'value', Number(this.inputValue).toFixed(this.decimalPrecision));
}
}

HTML Usage:
<input allowDecimal readonly name="Rate{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.Rate" required #rate="ngModel" decimalPrecision="4" inputValue="{{record.Rate}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not how Angular is supposed to be used. There are two issues with your code.

1. **Why it does not work**: When the value changes, you replace the value with a decimal representation. As you have two-way data-binding this will trigger the `valueChange` event, which will parse the input to a number (as `inputValue` is defined as type `number`), which will result in the decimals removed (as they are just zeros).
2. **Why it is not the Angular way**: You should not use the `renderer` to alter values of an input. Instead use an additional class variable which actually is of type string. Bind the inputs value to this field (as it is strings afterall that the input contains) and update your actual value if value of input changes `(onChange)`.

Comment: i am new to angular, it would be very helpful if you could provide a piece of code to achieve something similar, also i am using tofixed() which should ideally return a string representation with 4 decimal places

Comment: my main aim is to do everything in this directive

Comment: sorry I do not have the time to do that, please try my suggestion and ask if you have a specific question.